# need guidance regarding showing active/selected items in cart/basket with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating step by step order and I am currently struggling on "Your order" *(you can also call it basket or cart)* which is another column that displays the `.name` and `.price` for the `.selected` `.service`

What I am trying to accomplish is if you click on *Service #1* the `.name` and `.price` will be displayed in their appropiate `<li class="order">` `<span>` and that **works**.

Since this is a step by step order, once you select *Service #**x*** e.g. you will see changes in "Your order", and the next `<section>` will be visible *(Service #**x**.1, #**x**.2 and #**x**.3)* but if you click one of these items you will not see any changes in "Your order", and one of my questions is why?

Here's my code:

```
// YOUR ORDER
$(".service").on('click', function() {
  var selected = $('.selected');
  var name = selected.find('.name').html();
  var price = selected.find('.price').html();
  $("li.order > span.service_name").html(name).show();
  $("li.order > span.service_price").html(price).show();
});
```

Is it possible to make this code work so it grabs the `.name` and `.price` for any `.selected` item and if it's no longer selected, remove it from the list? Is there a efficient way to create this?

This is my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/superladremi/r0q0v7dn/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a `.service`, empty the order list, grab all `.selected` elements, and add them to the order list. https://jsfiddle.net/r0q0v7dn/3/

And for what it's worth, added some code to add up the prices so the total reflects the sum of the selected elements. https://jsfiddle.net/r0q0v7dn/4/

Comment: Of course, Michael. My hero, again(!) and on point as always. I totally understood this code. +1 wisdom for me. Now I will try to make the price calculation to update whenever a service is clicked. I'm buying you a coffee =)

Comment: @superladremi awesome :) btw added an update that sums the total in your order list. I'll take that coffee, too!! Cheers!

Comment: My god, one step ahead of me it seems, can I thank you somehow?!!!! You probably saved me days of research, alot of headscratching and most likely another post at stackoverflow. Thanks buddy <3

Answer (score 0):

Because your `var selected = $('.selected');` will take in consideration only the first element, you should do something like this:

```
  var selected = $('.selected').last();
```

Comment: I'll try to edit this code to see it in action, thanks for answering my question! :)